# HTTP Proxy support with WKWebView

Tags: ios, http, networking, proxy, wkwebview

Is there a way to configure WKWebView to go through a HTTP Proxy server? I know this is possible with NSURLSession directly, but I want to configure it so that all requests through the WKWebView browser go through a proxy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*NSURLSessionConfiguration* has a direct interface(*connectionProxyDictionary*) to do that , so it can be done easily

But, WkWebView does not have any direct interface like that,it requests ,renders the content out-of-process and so you can imagine like WkWebview instance is sandboxed from the rest of your app

WkWeView even ignores the cookies(NSHTTPCookieStorage), caches(NSURLCache) and Credentials(NSCredentialStorage) of NSURLSession & NSURLConnection likewise these network classes can't access cookies,caches and credentials of WkWebView instance.

The UIWebView does not do it out-of-process and so you can use NSURLProtocol as demonstrated in [CustomHTTPProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CustomHTTPProtocol/Introduction/Intro.html) sample to proxy to a server.

As of iOS 10, still there is no support for NSURLProtocol in WkWebView so you can't proxy using WkWebView.

If your proxy server supports tunnelling(VPN) then you can use *NetworkExtension.framework* and its classes(NEVPNManager, NEVPNProtocol, NEVPNConnection etc..) to direct all the network traffic of your app through your proxy server.