# Use a proxy for HTTP requests with WKWebView

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I have a problem, where I need to route HTTP requests from the IOS WebView through a HTTP proxy.

The intention is to route it through a HTTP proxy running Privoxy, so all tracking scripts and ads are removed. I want to provide a free app on the appstore, where people can browse without having to view ads and being tracked.

It seems that it is possible somehow with the UIWebView, but since it has become deprecated, I could imagine that other issues would start popping op, if I used that... I have not been able to find any sources officially nor unofficially, if the newer WKWebView can do this. If any of you know this and would share your knowledge on it, it would be much appreciated.

I have so far developed my full app in React Native, which seems to have *no way* of doing this at all, so before redeveloping everything in Swift, I want to make a bit more sure that it is actually possible there and thus meaningful to change...

Comment: May want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41068675/http-proxy-support-with-wkwebview

Comment: Turns out, you cannot solve this problem. Although it was a depressing answer, I got the probably most thorough tech answer ever from the following Apple employee that helped us:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/337570#337570

Sorry for giving a depressing answer back (the "accident of implementation rather than design" is especially depressing), but it is worth a read to figure out what the alternatives could be...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible with react native webview:

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/115